# std::bind not able to call the class member function: C++

Tags: c++11, boost

I have to implement `A valve Open function (for specified duration)`.
I am using `boost::asio::deadline_timer`

My class member function to open valve is:

```
bool Valves::valveOpen(ValveType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
        case eVentValve:
            tblMap_.digitalInput[eVentValveK1].setBit();
            if (tblMap_.digitalOutput[eOutK1VentValve].getBit())
            {
                isVentOpen_ = true;
            }
            return isVentOpen_;

        case eVacuumPumpValve:

....
....
}
```

Class member function to close the valve is:

```
bool Valves::valveClose(ValveType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case eVentValve:
        tblMap_.digitalInput[eVentValveK1].clearBit();
        if (!tblMap_.digitalOutput[eOutK1VentValve].getBit())
        {
            isVentOpen_ = false;
        }
        return !isVentOpen_;

    case eVacuumPumpValve:
....
....
}
```

I am trying to achieve the timer action as below

```
bool Valves::valveTimedOpen(ValveType type, int sec)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    switch (type)
    {
    case eVentValve:
    {
                    std::bind(&Valves::valveOpen, this, type); //Here
                    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(sec));
                    t.async_wait(std::bind(&Valves::valveClose, this, type));
                    boost::thread th(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
                    return true;
    }

    case eVacuumPumpValve:

.....
.....
}
```

The code hits the line `Here` i.e.

`std::bind(&Valves::valveOpen, this, type);` but it does not go to `bool Valves::valveOpen(ValveType type)` function.

Can someone let me know the issue with this code?

Answer (score 3):

Variables `io` and `t` go out of scope as soon as `valveTimedOpen` exits. You need to rethink the way you interact with the boost asio components e.g. the `io_service` could be a member of your class, and the timer could be dynamically allocated and needs to be deleted in the completion handler.

Also, keep in mind that if you plan on re-using an `io_service` object, you also need to `reset` it before calling `run` again.

Answer (score 0):

```
      auto fn = std::bind(&Test::Open, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1);
      fn(type);
```

Calls the `Open()` correctly.

`io_service` and `boost::deadline_timer` I have to make class member as suggested by @Ralf

Working Code:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>


class Test : public std::enable_shared_from_this <Test>
{
public:
    Test() :io(), timer(io){}
    void Open(int num);
    void Close(int num);
    void TimedOpen(int num, int dur);
    void Run();
private:
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
};

void Test::Open(int num)
{
    std::cout << "Open for Number : " << num << std::endl;
}

void Test::Close(int num)
{
    std::cout << "Close for Number : " << num << std::endl;
}

void Test::TimedOpen(int num, int dur)
{
    io.reset();
    auto fn = std::bind(&Test::Open, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1);
    fn(num);
    timer.expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::seconds(dur));
    timer.async_wait(std::bind(&Test::Close, shared_from_this(), num));
    Run();
    std::cout << "Function Exiting" << std::endl;
}

void Test::Run()
{
    boost::thread th(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
}

int main()
{
    auto t = std::make_shared<Test>();
    t->TimedOpen(5, 5);
    char line[128];
    while (std::cin.getline(line, 128))
    {
        if (strcmp(line, "\n")) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```